# What is hyperspace in linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra

In linear algebra text(Hoffman), it says "In a vector space of dimension $n$, a subspace of dimension $n-1$ is called hyperspace".

The problem is the following theorem.

> If $W$ is a $k$-dimensional subspace of an $n$-dimensional vector space V, then W is the intersection of $(n-k)$ hyperspaces in V.

I don't understand what $(n-k)$ hyperspaces is. The definition of hyperspace is $n-1$ subspace. Does it mean $(n-k-1)$ subspace?

I truly know the fact that where $W^0$ is the annihilator of $W$, " dim $W^0$ + dim$W$ = dim $V$ " holds. And by this formula, W is exactly the set of vectors $\alpha$ such that $f_i(\alpha) = 0$, $i = k+1,...,n $. if $\alpha_j (j=1,...n)$ is basis of V and $f_i(\alpha_j)=\delta_{ij}$.

The text says "In case $k=n-1$, $W$ is the null space of $f_n$, so it is proved.", but i can't understand why $k=n-1$ holds and why it is proved(actually i don't understand the proof).

Comment: You say you don't understand the proof. Please include more details of the proof so we can help you. For example, what does $f_i(\alpha) = \delta_{ij}$ mean? You've made no reference to the index $j$.

Comment: Oops i omited it.

Comment: Your proof is incorrect. The claim is not necessarily true for any particular basis of $V$.

Comment: I am confused by your confusion... you say "In the case that $k=n-1$, ..." and then ask why $k$ must be equal to $n-1$..?

We chose it that way. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you understand the phrase "four ten-storey buildings"? If so, replace "four" by "$n-k$" and "ten-storey buildings" by "hyperspaces" (or "$(n-1)$-dimensional subspaces"). Do you still follow?

Comment: The term used is not correct. This is properly called a [hyperplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane).

Comment: By (n-k) hyperspaces, they mean (n-k) **number of** hyperspaces. (already pointed out by @user1551)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition of hyperspace is an $(n-1)$-*dimensional* subspace.

For example, if $V$ is $(n=\ )\ 2$-dimensional, then hyperspaces are $(n-1=\ )\ 1$-dimensional subspaces (lines), and he claims that the $(k=\ )\ 0$-dimensional subspaces (points) are the intersection of $n-k = 2-0 = 2$ lines which should seem familiar.

If you want it to be $(n-k-1)$-dimensional subspaces, then here you would need every point to be a line!

Comment: Does it mean that $ker(f_i)$ is a hyperspace of $V$? I think it is hyperspace of $W$.

Comment: If $W$ is given as the space where $f_i(\alpha)=0$ for *all* $i\geq k+1$ then $W$ is a subspace of $\ker(f_m)$ for any fixed $m\geq k+1$.

Note that $\alpha\in\ker(f_m)$ only requires $f_m(\alpha)=0$, whereas in $\alpha\in W$ requires $f_i(\alpha)=0$ for *each* $i\geq k+1$, not just $m$.

Comment: Oh! I got it thanks.

Comment: What would be the dimension of a translation of a hyperspace? What is the difference between the maximal subset and a hyperspace of a space?

Answer (score 6):

It means that there are hyperspaces $H_1, H_2, \dots, H_{n-k}$ such that $H_1\cap H_2\cap \dots\cap H_{n-k} = W$. That is, the number of hyperspaces needed is $n - k$.

In the case of $k = n - 1$, $W$ is itself a hyperspace so you only need $1 = n - (n - 1)$ hyperspaces.